# SafetyNet Attestation API deprecation

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, safetynet

I'm getting this email from Google developers who remembers me to migrate to Play Integrity API.
[image]

My app is built using react-native and it uses [rnfirebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) library for Authentication, storage, and a few other services. We are not using AppCheck directly.

I could see the SafetyNet library inside my app which is being internally used by Firebase Auth.

There is an issue already open in the rn-firebase repo. The discussion there concludes to wait a bit more till the migration is done at the library side.

So my question is should I wait till it is done or can I do something from my side and will my app stop working after January 30th?

You can read the complete email from [here](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/discussions/6586)

Comment: Did you consider asking this question on the Github repo where the change is already being discussed?